# How do I make a file accessible to PHP only?

Tags: php, .htaccess, access-control

I have a PHP script that is supposed to scrape a database and I don't want that database to be accessed publicly. How do i make it so the file cannot be viewed like `https://example.com/database.file` but the PHP file can still scrape it.

Last time I tried disabling access to the file but the PHP file returned a 403 every time I tried to access it.

Next I viewed two questions on this website, but none could answer my problem.

Comment: Have you thought of putting the information into a database, this won't be accessible by the user except through the application.

Comment: You do not have to put your database file in a publically accessible directory.  You can move it outside the document root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a redirect condition for the file in apache/nginx to deny external use.

In Apache:

```
<FilesMatch "^(database\.file)$">
  Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

In Nginx:

```
location = /database.file {
        deny all;
        return 404;
}
```

Comment: In Nginx you would use the `internal` directive

Answer (score 0):

If you want your file to be hidden, IMO the simplest way is to redirect to your 404 file (file not found page) by URL rewriting.

something like:
`RewriteRule "^folder/myFile\.php$" "404.html" [QSA,L]`

URL rewriting will not affect PHP includes/requires or `file_get_contents` that deal directly with file system structure